# D3 resizable ellipse

Tags: d3.js, svg, resize, ellipse, resizable

I need to create a resizable ellipse in D3.  I'd like it to be scaled by grabbing a single drag handler in the lower right corner of the ellipse.  I've found several examples (like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/Pxbrf/) for resizable circles, but nothing for ellipse.  Any help would be great... Thanks!

Need similar solution to this:

```
window.onload = function() {
var R = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500),
    c = R.circle(100, 100, 50).attr({
        fill: "hsb(.8, 1, 1)",
        stroke: "none",
        opacity: .5
    }),
    s = R.circle(125, 125, 15).attr({
        fill: "hsb(.8, .5, .5)",
        stroke: "none",
        opacity: .5
    });
var start = function () {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");    
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");

    this.sizer.ox = this.sizer.attr("cx");    
    this.sizer.oy = this.sizer.attr("cy")

    this.attr({opacity: 1});
    this.sizer.attr({opacity: 1});
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
    this.sizer.attr({cx: this.sizer.ox + dx, cy: this.sizer.oy + dy});
},
up = function () {
    // restoring state
    this.attr({opacity: .5});
    this.sizer.attr({opacity: .5});
},
rstart = function() {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");        

    this.big.or = this.big.attr("r");
},
rmove = function (dx, dy) {
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    this.attr({cx: this.ox + dy, cy: this.oy + dy});
    this.big.attr({r: this.big.or + 
                   (dy < 0 ? -1 : 1) * Math.sqrt(2*dy*dy)});
};
c.drag(move, start, up);    
c.sizer = s;
s.drag(rmove, rstart);
s.big = c;
};
```

Only I need it coded for use in d3.js instead of Raphael.js

Comment: There's nothing built into d3 for this so you'd have to code the resize handles and resizing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have given a circle grows uniformly i.e. both in x axis and y axis but in ellipse it can grow in x axis and in y axis(i.e. both minor axis and major axis cam be changed).

In my example below i am using transform scale to increase and decrease the size of the ellipse as whole.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var scale = 1;
svg.attr("width", 500).attr("height", 500);
var g = svg.append("g")
g.append("ellipse")
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return 300;
})


    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return 100;
})
    .attr("rx", 150)
    .attr("ry", 100);
d3.select("#increase").on("click", increase);
d3.select("#decrease").on("click", decrease);
//increase via scaling
function increase() {
    scale +=0.1;
    g.transition().delay("100").attr("transform", "scale("+scale+")");
    
}
function decrease() {
    scale -=0.1;
    g.transition().delay("100").attr("transform", "scale("+scale+")");
}
```

```css
ellipse {
    stroke: none;
    fill: brown;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button id="increase">Increase</button>
    <button id="decrease">Decrease</button>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!